# Runtime exception when upgrading WorkManager from 1.0.0-alpha02 to 1.0.0-alpha03

Tags: android, android-workmanager

When I upgrade `WorkManager` from 1.0.0-alpha02 to 1.0.0-alpha03.

### Old build.gradle

```
def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
// optional - Firebase JobDispatcher support
implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:$work_version"
```

### New build.gradle

```
def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha03"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
// optional - Firebase JobDispatcher support
implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:$work_version"
```

---

I notice I need to make the following changes

### 1.0.0-alpha02

```
public WorkerResult doWork() {
```

### 1.0.0-alpha03

```
public Result doWork() {
```

---

That's not an major issue though. However, if we tend to upgrade an app, which is previously already running using `1.0.0-alpha02`, we will get the following runtime exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: WorkTag.tag, WorkTag.work_spec_id (code 1555)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1679)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:242)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkDatabaseMigrations$1.migrate(WorkDatabaseMigrations.java:73)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:85)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:133)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.compileStatement(RoomDatabase.java:244)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.createNewStatement(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:65)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.getStmt(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:72)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.acquire(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:87)
    at androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpecDao_Impl.resetScheduledState(WorkSpecDao_Impl.java:337)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.rescheduleEligibleWork(WorkManagerImpl.java:514)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

May I know what are some workarounds, to avoid such run-time exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We introduced implicit tags for `Worker`s in `alpha03`. In the rare case that you have a pre-existing tag, this will happen. We will address this issue in `alpha04`. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you. We hope once `alpha04` released, we can seamlessly upgrade from `alpha02` to `alpha04`. Meanwhile, we has stopped upgrading to `alpha03`, due to this issue.

Comment: Hi Rahul, do you have any estimated time frame, for `alpha04`? As, we gonna plan to see whether we should wait for `alpha04`. Thank you.

Comment: `alpha04` was released more than a week ago. Here is the release notes:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes